Automatic assigning t-test and ANOVA to variables in tbl_continuous in gtsummary
trial |> 
  select(trt,marker,grade,response) |>
  tbl_continuous(marker,
                 statistic = ~"{mean} ({sd})") |> 
  add_p()


I want to use t-test and ANOVA in add_p(), I did not find enough documentation in this part or how to use specific version of t-test and how to use ANOVA only when there are more than 2 levels and t-test when there are 2 levels.
The only thing I found in documentation is
"test.args
Containing additional arguments to pass to tests that accept arguments. For example, add an argument for all t-tests, use test.args = all_tests("t.test") ~ list(var.equal = TRUE)."
I tried this
trial |> 
  select(trt,marker,grade,response) |>
  tbl_continuous(marker,
                 statistic = ~"{mean} ({sd})") |> 
  add_p(test.args = all_tests("t.test") ~ list(var.equal = TRUE))

And it gave me the same table above with no change.
I want to know how to use t-test/ANOVA instead of the default Wilcoxon/Kruskal-Wallis in tbl_continuous . Also, it seems there is no theme elements or themes regarding tbl_continuous in the documentation, I want to know if there is something like that or some examples on how to use statistical tests in add_p()
Edit: I tried creating a custom function to do that
# Function to determine the appropriate test
get_test <- function(variable) {
  if (length(unique(variable)) == 2) {
    return("t.test")
  } else {
    return("aov")
  }
}

# Create a named vector of tests for each variable
tests = sapply(trial, get_test)

# Create a named list for the statistic argument
stat_tests <- setNames(as.list(tests), names(tests))


trial |> 
  select(trt,marker,grade,response) |>
  tbl_continuous(marker,
                 statistic = ~"{mean} ({sd})") |> 
  add_p(test = stat_tests)



Use the add_p(test) argument to change the default test.

@DanielD.Sjoberg
Yes, I think this is what was missing, I found also a good explanation in add_p() in tbl_summary, but how can I specify ANOVA for more than 2 levels and t-test for 2 levels variables like in the above scenario?

In the description of the test argument, there is a link to another file listing all the available tests

@DanielD.Sjoberg
Yes, I checked them, but what I mean I want to change the defaults for 2 level variables and 3 or more level variables, I can do that in tbl_summary using  theme elements like add_p.tbl_summary-attr:test.continuous_by2 and add_p.tbl_summary-attr:test.continuous, but I cannot do that for tbl_continuous which will require me to sort variables every time according to their levels, and assign the suitable test

Those are not available for tbl_continuous(), unfortunately.

Specify the tests that you want to perform for each variable in a list.
trial |> 
  select(trt, marker, grade,response) |>
  tbl_continuous(marker,
                 statistic = ~"{mean} ({sd})") |> 
  add_p(test=list(trt~"t.test",
                  grade="aov",
                  response="t.test"))



Check:
round(t.test(marker~trt, data=trial)$p.value, 2)  # 0.12
round(summary(aov(marker~grade, data=trial))[[1]][1,5], 3)  # 0.025
round(t.test(marker~response, data=trial)$p.value, 2)  # 0.12


Thanks, but I was talking about something automatic like the defaults, when there is 2 variables use this test and when there is more than 2 levels use that one, which will be more practical in high number of variables, is something like this available in gtsummary?

See the help page of add_p.tbl_summary, which states: The default test used in add_p() primarily depends on these factors: ... . And then: "wilcox.test" when by variable has two levels and variable is continuous,  "krustkal.test" when by variable has more than two levels and variable is continuous, "chisq.test.no.correct" for categorical variables with all expected cell counts >=5, and "fisher.test" for categorical variables with any expected cell count <5.

Yes, I checked it, and what I want is to change is these defaults, I can do that in tbl_summary using theme elements like add_p.tbl_summary-attr:test.continuous_by2 and add_p.tbl_summary-attr:test.continuous, but I cannot do that for tbl_continuous, I want to know how to change the defaults instead of typing test names manually for each variable every time I use the function!

You can't change the defaults unless you write your own package. :D
